Ambiguity between Statistic Normality Test vs Visual Normality Check
I'm learning some basic EDA using the Boston housing price dataset and I want to filter out outliers in the feature columns. To do that I first wanted to understand what distribution each of my feature column is so that I can choose the appropriate outlier mechanism.
To identify the normality, I used qq-plot so that I can inspect it visually and then I used the Shapiro-Wilk test so that I can get the p value and determine if I should reject the hypotheses. I get contradictory results. For example, the qq-plot for a feature column called RM looks like this:

The Shapiro-Wilk test which I have implemented as below:
from typing import NoReturn

import pandas as pd
from scipy.stats import shapiro

def test_for_normality(df: pd.DataFrame) -> NoReturn:
    """
    Performs Shapiro-Wilk normality test on each column of the DataFrame.

    Args:
        df (pd.DataFrame): Input DataFrame.

    Returns:
        None
    """
    print("Shapiro-Wilk Normality Test Results:")
    for column in df.columns:
        stat, p = shapiro(df[column])
        print(f"Column '{column}': Statistics={stat:.3f}, p-value={p:.3f}")

Prints the following for the RM feature when I ran it:
Column 'RM': Statistics=0.961, p-value=0.000

Could anyone please help me understand it?

Unless you can confirm that you outliers are erroneous completely at random (ECAR), you should not filter them out of your analysis. If they're not erroneous then you should model them instead of remove them. Often this is a matter of choice of probability distribution.

@Galen is right. Moreover, I would recommend to never use the formal test for normality. The test is not robust see this excellent paper from Tsagris: https://www.ajodo.org/article/S0889-5406(21)00038-X/pdf

Is there any statistical approach to tell if my outliers are ECAR?

First, I agree with @Galen.  Second, what is "ECAR"?  Third,, the appropriate outlier mechanism is your brain and substantive knowledge. Why do you think a variable must follow any particular forma distribution? Sure, lots of variables are approximately normal, or approximately something else. But so?  An outlier is a surprising point. Finally, I see no contradiction between the plot and the SW test in your post.

@joesan No, there is no statistical approach to tell if your outliers are ECAR. It is a matter of causal assumptions and domain knowledge.

@PeterFlom ECAR is a close analog of missing completely at random (MCAR). In fact they're the same problem in terms of causal inference: you are not observing the true value (whether that be missingness represented by NULL or N/A or some other value that isn't correct that we might call a measurement error) for reasons that are background noise. I don't have the time to fully explain in terms of Pearl's do calculus right now, but that is the context in which they can both be described and compared.

Thanks for all the insights, but my original post is about identifying why I see ambiguous detail when visualizing and applying a statistic measure to check if it is a normal distribution or not,.

There is absolutely no contradiction between the qq-plot and the Shapiro-test. The qq-plot show a wavy pattern and deviations at each tail of the distribution. Because no variable is every truly normally distributed, the Shapiro-test will practially always be significant if the sample size gets large. More on all that here.

Can you explain what ambiguity or contradiction you're seeing? The QQ plot shows that the data is not normal, and the test rejects the null of the data being normal.  So, what more do you need?

Ok, so may be I need to understand how to interpret the QQ plot. To me since most of the data points fell on the 45 degree line, it sounded as though it is a normal distribution.

But "most" is not "all".  Also, when you say "on" your mean "close to". These are not language quibbles; they are the entire point. No data sample can exactly resemble a normal distribution. In practice, while normality is rejected here, that distribution is close to normal. If it is to be a predictor, normality is not even an ideal.  I wouldn't say that there were any marked outliers, and I wouldn't e.g. consider transforming it. These are judgment calls based on experience. It's hard to get started here until you have some experience, but that is true of statistics generally,

... you mean ...

Back to the problem: If there are outliers here, they are outliers in the space of all the variables. An outlier on one variable might make perfect sense given the other variables. Conversely, an outlier in some space might not be evident on any univariate plot. It is easy to imagine a scatter plot where an outlier in $x, y$ space is not an outlier in either marginal distribution.

As already stated in comments, there is no conflict between the qqplot and the small p+value from the Shapiro-Wilk test. The plot shows clearly that both tails are considerably heavier than implied by the normal distribution. A considerable number of data points participates in this heavy tails, so it cannot just be a random fluke, and that is what the p-value tells you.
If that deviation from normality is important for your analysis we cannot tell you, because that depends on what your goal is, and you did not tell us.
